# How to coordinate shutdown with many goroutines

Tags: go

Say I have a function

```
type Foo struct {}

func (a *Foo) Bar() {
    // some expensive work - does some calls to redis
}
```

which gets executed within a goroutine at some point in my app. Lots of these may be executing at any given point. Prior to application termination, I would like to ensure all remaining goroutines have finished their work.

Can I do something like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    wg sync.WaitGroup
}

func (a *Foo) Close() {
    a.wg.Wait()
}

func (a *Foo) Bar() {
    a.wg.Add(1)
    defer a.wg.Done()

    // some expensive work - does some calls to redis
}
```

Assuming here that Bar gets executed within a goroutine and many of these may be running at a given time and that Bar should not be called once Close is called and Close is called upon a sigterm or sigint.

Does this make sense?

Usually I would see the Bar function look like this:

```
func (a *Foo) Bar() {
    a.wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer a.wg.Done()
        // some expensive work - does some calls to redis
    }()
}
```

Comment: what you are looking for is called graceful shutdown https://medium.com/@kpbird/golang-gracefully-stop-application-23c2390bb212

Comment: Can the goroutines get blocked for long time? What do you want to do then? I believe in general you should have a way to signal child that app is shutting down but that is only possible if say child are non-blocking

Comment: It may block for short time, but the thing im aiming to achieve is that we complete all work before shutting down. In my main app I am implementing a time-out so that if `Close` takes too long, it will still gracefully shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `WaitGroup` is the right answer. You can use `WaitGroup.Add` at anytime that the counter is greater than zero, as per [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

> Note that calls with a positive delta that occur when the counter is zero must happen before a Wait. Calls with a negative delta, or calls with a positive delta that start when the counter is greater than zero, may happen at any time. Typically this means the calls to Add should execute before the statement creating the goroutine or other event to be waited for. If a WaitGroup is reused to wait for several independent sets of events, new Add calls must happen after all previous Wait calls have returned. See the WaitGroup example.

But one trick is that, you should always keep the counter greater than zero, before `Close` is called. That usually means you should call `wg.Add` in `NewFoo` (or something like that) and `wg.Done` in `Close`. And to prevent multiple calls to `Done` ruining the wait group, you should wrap `Close` into `sync.Once`. You may also want to prevent new `Bar()` from being called.

Answer (score 0):

`WaitGroup` is one way, however, the Go team introduced the `errgroup` for your use case exactly. The most inconvenient part of leaf bebop's answer, is the disregard for error handling. Error handling is the reason `errgroup` exists. And idiomatic go code should *never* swallow errors.

However, keeping the signatures of your `Foo` struct, (except a cosmetic `workerNumber`)—and no error handling—my proposal looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

type Foo struct {
    errg errgroup.Group
}

func NewFoo() *Foo {
    foo := &Foo{
        errg: errgroup.Group{},
    }
    return foo
}

func (a *Foo) Bar(workerNumber int) {
    a.errg.Go(func() error {
        select {
        // simulates the long running clals
        case <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(10))):
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("worker %d completed its work", workerNumber))
            return nil
        }
    })
}

func (a *Foo) Close() {
    a.errg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    foo := NewFoo()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        foo.Bar(i)
    }

    <-time.After(time.Second * 5)
    fmt.Println("Waiting for workers to complete...")
    foo.Close()
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

The benefit here, is that if you introduce error handling in your code (you should), you only need to slightly modify this code: In short, `errg.Wait()` would return the first redis error, and `Close()` could propagate this up through the stack (to main, in this case).

Utilizing the `context.Context` package as well, you would also be able to immediately cancel any running redis call, if one fails. There are examples of this in the `errgroup` documentation.

Comment: While `errgroup` provides a single error handling point, it is hardly useful. OP does not describe how error should be handled (e.g., abort at the first error, or tolerate no more than X errors, etc.,). I would say use waitgroup and adds your own error handling code.

Comment: I agree that it is not useful for OP's code as it stands now, but OP opened up for commenting on whether or not his/hers question made sense. I suggest it does not make sense without error handling. Add error handling—and `errgroup` becomes wildly useful.

Comment: In my actual implementation, my `Bar` function returns an `error` and that gets bubbled up.

Answer (score 0):

I think waiting indefinitely for all the go routines to finish is not the right way.
If one of the go routines get blocked or say it hangs due to some reason and never terminates successfully, what should happen kill the process or wait for go routines to finish ?

Instead you should wait with some timeout and kill the app irrespective of whether all the routines have finished or not.

**Edit: Original ans**
Thanks @leaf bebop for pointing it out. I misunderstood the question.

Context package can be used to signal all the go routines to handle kill signal.

`appCtx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())`

Here appCtx will have to be passed to all the go routines.

On exit signal call `cancel()`.

functions running as go routines can handle how to handle cancel context.

[Using context cancellation in Go](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/golang/2018-06-17-golang-using-context-cancellation/)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. OP wants to ensure all `Bar` that is running will *not* be cancelled when `Close` is called - he wants them running till finished.

Comment: Yes that is right and in my specific use case, I am doing a sort of timeout in my main app using `time.After(ShutdownTimeoutSeconds * time.Second)` within a `select {}` and either we get the timeout or we get a final shutdown signal which is signaled after the `Close()` finishes.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern i use a lot is: https://play.golang.org/p/ibMz36TS62z

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type response struct {
    message string
}

func task(i int, done chan response) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    done <- response{fmt.Sprintf("%d done", i)}
}

func main() {

    responses := GetResponses(10)

    fmt.Println("all done", len(responses))
}

func GetResponses(n int) []response {
    donequeue := make(chan response)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(value int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            task(value, donequeue)
        }(i)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(donequeue)
    }()
    responses := []response{}
    for result := range donequeue {
        responses = append(responses, result)
    }

    return responses
}
```

this makes it easy to throttle as well: https://play.golang.org/p/a4MKwJKj634

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type response struct {
    message string
}

func task(i int, done chan response) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    done <- response{fmt.Sprintf("%d done", i)}
}

func main() {

    responses := GetResponses(10, 2)

    fmt.Println("all done", len(responses))
}

func GetResponses(n, concurrent int) []response {

    throttle := make(chan int, concurrent)
    for i := 0; i < concurrent; i++ {
        throttle <- i
    }
    donequeue := make(chan response)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        <-throttle
        go func(value int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            throttle <- 1
            task(value, donequeue)
        }(i)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(donequeue)
    }()
    responses := []response{}
    for result := range donequeue {
        responses = append(responses, result)
    }

    return responses
}
```